# How can I use Jquery in rails 3.2.8?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

All the tutorials I've read tell me to use the "public/javascripts" folder. But there is no such folder in rails 3.2.8

- where do I place my jquery code?
- isn't Jquery included in Rails 3.2.8?

Comment: Please mention what tutorials you looked into so that you get your point through.

Comment: http://blog.bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default Rails application (> 3.2) includes the jQuery gem on line 23 of the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

You place your jQuery code in a custom JavaScript file--e.g., `hello.js`--in the following path:

```
app/assets/javascripts/
```

Example:

```
app/assets/javascripts/hello.js
```

In `hello.js`, make sure you include your jQuery code inside of this block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

That's it. You're ready to use jQuery in Rails. (This works because of line 15 in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`)

```
//= require_tree .
```

This line says to include everything in the `javascripts` directory.

Comment: By default in the Rails 3.2+ Rails uses the assets pipeline and CoffeeScript. When you create a model a js.coffee file is created, if you don't want to use CoffeeScript but stay in pure JQuery you can rename these files to .js instead of js.coffee

Answer (score 0):

You need the gem. Maybe this will help you:

http://c.kat.pe/post/how-to-use-jquery-for-rails-3/

Comment: then use the assets path. per default it is app/assets

Comment: Oh I got it!   I just put the code in the "layouts/application.html.erb" inside the <head> tag, with out the "<script src="../jquery.js"></script>"   ...and the part that SHOULD go in the <body> tag,   goes in the .erb files (in the "views" folder) :)

Comment: ChuckE, I tried to put the Jquery code (without the "<script src="../jquery.js"></script>")       ...and it didnt work...   ...is it a bad practice to put Jquery in the "layouts/application.html.erb" ?

Comment: if you are using asset pipeline, it is good practice to declare the jquery file in the manifest file and declare this in the layout. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Answer (score 0):

You can write a jquery code and put file as file_name.js in Javascript folder and call this file in your layout file. 
You can refer  http://jqueryui.com/