# Jquery not loading in rails 3.2.6

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble figuring out why Jquery isn't loading in my rails 3.2.6 app. When I use "$" in the browser console, it is said that:

```
function $() { [Command Line API] }
```

Then, when I view the source in the browser, it seems the Jquery not loading:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In Application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>   
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2230354 TRY THIS

Comment: jQuery likely is loading in your app. You've included it into your app's manifest, application.js, which you've noted is included in your app.

Comment: Just testing $ isn't enough, many libraries and applications define `$`. Test if `$.fn.jquery` is defined.

Comment: @KevinB It is said that "[11:46:01.817] TypeError: $.fn is undefined"...But I have require the jquery in the application.js, what can I do then?

Comment: @Lisa what does jQuery.fn.jquery give you?

Comment: @KevinB It is said "[07:04:40.207] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"...

Comment: That means `$` is not jQuery.

Comment: @KevinB does that mean the jQuery is not loaded to the rail app?

Comment: @Lisa not necessarily, something could be overwriting `$`

Comment: @KevinB that is interesting, as there is nothing in the app could overwrite it... is there any way to check what is overwriting $? have no clue what happened here ..-_-||

Comment: For all i know ruby-on-rails could be including some js library of it's own that defines $. View the source of your page and look at what js scripts are being included.

Comment: @KevinB By checking the source, this is the only js scripts are being called..<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> there is no information about the jQuery...

Comment: open up application.js?body=1 and see what it's doing.

Comment: Hey, @KevinB, It seems that there are only " *= require_self
 *= require_tree .", is this normal?

Comment: @Lisa I have no idea, i've never used RoR

Answer (score -1):

```
javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
javascript_include_tag "jquery-rails.js"
```

For more Details check this site [CLICK HERE](http://bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/)

ALSO chk this question [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481996/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-rails-3-2-8)